# How to commit removal of files in SVN

Tags: svn, commit

I've changed the names of some files in my project. I would like to commit removal of files with old names on svn server.

RabbitCVS can't do it. Only possible action on missing files is "restore".
Is it possible to commit removal from commandline ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the command line yu can tell SVN to delete a file (even if it doesnt exist anymore in your local repository) with

```
svn del yourfile
```

(del, rm, remove are aliases)

and then commit it with

```
svn ci
```

The cleanest way is to rename the file with (for this one I think the old file needs to be present, maybe you can force it though)

```
svn mv youroldfile yournewfile
```

(mv, ren, rename are aliases)

Answer (score 0):

The command for the commandline is `svn rm $FILENAME`.

But if you renamed your files you may want to use `svn mv $OLDFILE $NEWFILE` to preserve the history.